# How to check if one JS script is not loaded twice or more?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working in Symfony Project, with Twig template engine.
I have a form.html.twig file where I have One big form, and one little that can be generated as many times as I want. 
So, when I press the "+" button, a new sub-form appears.
This form appears from prototype.html.twig file, where is stored all HTML of the form, with included JS.

It looks like :

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered text-center" style="margin-bottom:0px;">  
    <tr class="active">
        <td style="vertical-align:middle; padding-top:9px; padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px;"> <span style ="font-size: 24px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span></p>    </td> 
        <td>{{ form_row(form.date) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.value) }}</td>
        <td> {{ form_label(form.type, 'Value as % of') }}
              {{ form_widget(form.type) }} </td> 
        <td>{{ form_row(form.frequency) }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.duration) }}  </td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.agreement) }}</td>
        <td class="deleteButton" style="vertical-align:middle;"><a href="#"><button class="btn-sm btn-danger" style="border-radius:100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $('.deleteButton').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
</script>


{% block javascripts %}
<script src="{{asset('js/endingDateCalculator.js')}}"></script>
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

Take a look to block javascripts. In this block I have a script that calculate ending date in my sub-form. So, once I click the "+" button appears a new form, and the script endingDateCalculator is running and connected to work with this form.

I'm a little bit afraid that if I click more than one time to "+", with other words...if I have more than 1 sub-forms, this script is called again and again, that slows the page speed, or/and can make bugs with working in the same time.

It is calling again and again or not?
If yes, how can i solve it?
I tried to link the endingDateCalculator.js to the form.html.twig (base template), but in this case this script is not working when I generate a new form.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about symfony, but one of the options may be this

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

=========

from https://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx